# Finding a lean alternative for Kiwi browser (scriptable browsers)

Tags: android, web-browser, mobile, performance, browser-extension

I'm looking for a  browser on Android that is scriptable (run scripts against web servers) and lean—basically a Kiwi Browser that is much leaner, ideally <1.6MB.

---

Bonus points:

1. works without lag on cheap/old Android devices.
2. can perform enough JavaScript out-of-the-box to work well with popular websites of the time.

Comment: Any reason for the `<1.6MB` limit?

Comment: @jmizv, **ideally** means not a limit. 1.6 seems like a good budget (for 2023). [ There is room for improvement otherwise. / Can you imagine installing a 20MB / 200MB app? just not for me and similar folks ] Separately, btw a photo is pretty expensive (now) for a photo if it is >2.5mb.

Comment: I'm nto sure what you mean by "run scripts against web servers". If you mean that literally, you do not need a browser. Yoo do need a client, but not necessarilly a browser. Try something like PostMan. There's an Android version, but it's under developemt - https://github.com/TakuCoder/postman  Also, take a look at https://alternativeto.net/browse/search/?q=postman

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica, frankly I can't pull the relevant ram at this time (not even when I wrote the reply to jmizv whose comment came 7mths post OP) even if I may come across the problem again in the future. But it's something that **kiwi browser** can already do. Also if I wanted a postman it's unlikely I would have asked for a browser. Separately, "scriptable" might mean more greasemonkey/chromeext than postman.

Comment: Sounds like I need to look into Kiki browser ;-)  +1